# Unable to import models

Tags: python, django

I tried to execute

> > > from django.db import models

but it gave the following error.. :(

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.2-py2.6.egg/django/db/__init__.py", 
line 14, in <module>
if not settings.DATABASES:
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.2-py2.6.egg/django/utils/functional.py",
line 276, in __getattr__
self._setup()
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.2-py2.6.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", 
line 38, in _setup
raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is 
undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable   
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to do this import from the shell/terminal? If so you need to navigate into your Django project directory and type `python manage.py shell` before executing your import.

Comment: Thank u:) That seemed so simple but only when you said :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in os.environ variables to specify which your settings file is. It seems you try to use django models outside a django app. What do you try to achieve? If you just want to test with python shell,  you can use the Django  shell from a Django app dir:

```
manage.py shell --settings=settings
```

UPDATE: solartic was faster ;)